# A time limit/goal tracker on application usage for Windows?

Tags: windows, time-management, productivity

I need a Windows application that can limit my time on a group of applications - eg video games, youtube, facebook etc.

Furthermore I want to be able to set a goal on the total hours of work applications per day - say the goal is to reach 8 hours of usage per day so that I can see that I'm being productive for that day.

I found the below software that helps with viewing statistics but it doesn't set a limit or goal for a group of application as per my requirement.

[RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) and [Procrastitracker](http://strlen.com/procrastitracker/)

I'm currently using [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/), but it doesn't drill down to the type of application I'm using. For example, I could be playing video games and it will still be counted as the hours spent on the computer.

Is there any application that can do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

## RescueTime does allow setting a goal for a group of applications:

[image: image description]

All you need to do is assigning the apps you want to a specific category, so that you can set to it when creating a goal. If you use the premium plan, you can be alerted when you have exceeded your goal.